# Which of the following probabilities CANNOT be found using the binomial distribution?

Tags: probability

> 1. The probability that 3 out of 8 tosses of a coin will result in
>      heads
>
> 2.The probability of getting exactly five face cards when
>   drawing five cards from a standard deck of 52 cards without
>   replacement
>
> (3) When randomly choosing a family with four children,
>   the probability that it will have exactly two boys and two girls as
>   children, if having a boy or a girl is equally likely
>
> (4)   The
>   probability that a student randomly guessing will get at least 8 out
>   of 10 multiple-choice questions correct (assuming every question has
>   five choices)

To me, all of these scenarios seem like I can apply the binomial distribution formula except for (2) . I believe I can use it on (1) and (3) and (4). For (2) though, the probabilities will change due to no replacement. I think this breaks the formula. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep.  All but 2 (because of no replacement).  Use hypergeometric distribution for that!

Comment: Thank you Mr. Stork! Doubt is an annoying thing

Comment: Doubt is *essential* for learning and understanding!